# C++ - Overloaded Operator in Derived Class not working

Tags: c++, class, friend, derived-class

Okay, so the overloaded operator for the derived class is not working. It is only using the overloaded operator in the base class. Any ideas why?

Base class operator in class definition header file:

```
friend ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const PocketMonster & p);
```

Base class operator:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const PocketMonster & p)
{
    out << endl << "(Monster Types: Type 1 = Fire, Type 2 = Water, Type 3 = Grass)" << endl 
    << "PocketMonster Information: " << endl << "Name: " << p.name << endl
    << "Status (0=Dead, 1=Alive): " << p.status << endl << "Level: " << p.level << endl 
    << "Strength: " << p.strength << endl
    <<  endl << "(Weapon Types: 1 = Fire, 2 = Water, 3 = Grass, 4 = Normal)" << endl
    << p.name << "'s Weapon Information: " << endl << "Weapon type: " << p.get_weaptype() << endl
    << "Weapon durability: " << p.get_weapdura() << endl << "Weapon level required: " << p.get_weaplvl() << endl << endl;
    return out;
}
```

Derived class overloaded operator in class definition header file:

```
friend ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const FireMonster & p);
```

Derived class overloaded operator:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const FireMonster & p)
{
    return out << static_cast<const PocketMonster&>(p) << endl << "FireMonster Attributes:" << endl << "Temperature: " << p.temperature << endl;

}
```

And here's a function where it tries to output the information

```
void displayLosers(vector<PocketMonster *> p)
{
    for (int i=0; i<p.size(); i++)
    {
        if (p[i]->get_status() == false)
        {
            cout << p[i]->get_name() << " is a loser." << endl;
            cout << *(p[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: Is it perhaps because your losers are all of the derived class by coincidence? It is impossible to tell w/o more info.

Comment: @Anycorn, the output is the derived class text when the input is a base-class item.

Comment: all `p` elements are of type `PocketMonster` as far as `<<` is concerned - there is no way it can resolve that it is fire monster (without frowned-upon RTTI).  Most likely you want to provide a virtual `print` method.

Comment: @Anycorn I originally had a virtual print function to make the overloaded operator "fake virtual" but now I have to make it a friend for an assignment

Answer (score 1):

Add virtual function `Output` to the base class (at public or protected section):

```
virtual ostream & Output (ostream & out) const;

// ...

ostream & PocketMonster::Output (ostream & out) const
{
    out << endl << "(Monster Types: Type 1 = Fire, Type 2 = Water, Type 3 = Grass)" << endl 
    << "PocketMonster Information: " << endl << "Name: " << p.name << endl
    << "Status (0=Dead, 1=Alive): " << p.status << endl << "Level: " << p.level << endl 
    << "Strength: " << p.strength << endl
    <<  endl << "(Weapon Types: 1 = Fire, 2 = Water, 3 = Grass, 4 = Normal)" << endl
    << p.name << "'s Weapon Information: " << endl << "Weapon type: " << p.get_weaptype() << endl
    << "Weapon durability: " << p.get_weapdura() << endl << "Weapon level required: " << p.get_weaplvl() << endl << endl;
    return out;
}
```

and override it in derived class:

```
virtual ostream & Output (ostream & out) const;

// ...

ostream & FireMonster::Output (ostream & out) const
{
    return out << PocketMonster::Output(out) << endl << "FireMonster Attributes:" << endl << "Temperature: " << p.temperature << endl;
}
```

Then rewrite `operator<<` for the base class in the following way:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const PocketMonster & p)
{
    return p.Output(out);
}
```

and remove `operator<<` for derived class.

Comment: I get what you did, but I have to use friend in the overloaded operator function for my assignment. I just don't know how to incorporate polymorphism and friend functions together.

Comment: @user3083970 Friend function cannot be virtual (because it is not a class method). So I don't know how to solve your task.